# Java: Illegal type 'void' in ASyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hopefully you can shine some light on this for me.

I'm trying to create the following **AsyncTask** in Java for an Android app. When I enter the below code, Android Studio highlights both the '**void**' params with the error:

> "Illegal Type: Void".

After a number of google searches I still can't understand what the problem is here (and in honesty, I'm quite confused about the whole thing!).

```
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<URL, void, void> {

    protected void doInBackground(URL... inputURL) {

        URL searchURL = inputURL[0];

        //Step 2: Get Data
        String JSONdata = getJSONdata(searchURL);

        //Step 3: Parse JSON
        ArrayList books = parseJSON(JSONdata);

        updateUI(books);

    }
}
```

Appreciate any info you can send my way!

Comment: Cannot use `void`. Use `Void` instead.

Comment: Anything you use as a generic type must inherit from `Object`. The `Void` class is the usual way of representing `void`.

Comment: Looks like you are getting JSON from a URL. Perhaps you should try [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the class instead, **capital V**

```
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {
```

Answer (score 6):

AsyncTask uses generics. So use **Void** instead of **void**. Similarly, if you want to use integer use **Integer** and not **int**.